# What is the fastest way to do this in asp.mvc 3.0 + razor

Tags: sorting, asp.net-mvc-3, razor, filter

Need to be able to sort, filter, page the data. That's it. Using the asp.mvc on top of EF 4.1. Just need the listed functionality, no editors.

Answer (score 0):

Sorting and Paging are available out of the box using the WebGrid Helper. There is a good introduction in the [ASP.net Blog](http://weblogs.asp.net/shijuvarghese/archive/2010/10/08/using-the-webgrid-helper-in-asp-net-mvc-3-beta.aspx).